# NSNumberFormatter Text Field Thousand Separator

Tags: objective-c, nsnumberformatter

I'm programming credit calculator and I want the numbers formating with the (local) thousands separator when a user enters a number.

For example `100000` should become `100.000` (local).

How can I do that in my example?

```
NSNumberFormatter *nf = [[[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[nf setNumberStyle: NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[nf setRoundingMode: NSNumberFormatterRoundHalfUp];
[nf setMaximumFractionDigits: 2];

double loanAmount = [[nf numberFromString: tbxLoanAmount.text] floatValue];
double intRate = [[nf numberFromString: annualInterestRate.text] floatValue];
double NRate = [[nf numberFromString: NInterestRate.text] floatValue];
double years = [[nf numberFromString: noOfYears.text] floatValue];
double residual = [[nf numberFromString: residualvalue.text] floatValue];
```

Thanks a lot!

D

Comment: Don't you mean `100.000` should become `100000`, not the other way around? Also, doesn't a `NSNumberFormatter` have the current locale format by default? Is it not doing so?

Comment: I think that 100000 should become 100.000.

Comment: If the thousands separator is `.`, then if your string is `100.000`, then the number you get from it should be one hundred thousand, no?

Comment: Yes with thousands separator (.) Euro or (,) US.

Comment: And yes it is a hundred thousand.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to set the followings to your number formatter:

```
[nf setGroupingSize:3];
[nf setCurrencyGroupingSeparator:@"."];

// you should create a string from number
NSNumber n = [NSNumber numberWithLong: 100000];

NSString str = [nf stringFromNumber: n];

NSLog(@"My number: %@", str);
```

Comment: No, again the same thing! I tried it earlier!

I do not know where I'm wrong!

Comment: I've just recognized that you do not create a string from your number. The formatting settings like currency grouping are used only if you create a string from a number. Or do I completely misunderstood your case?

Comment: Also, don't forget nf.usesGroupingSeparator = YES;